# Multiple Carousels in Jtabs

Tags: tabs, jcarousel

So I finally got the tabs and first carousel working but when I try to pull up a second carousel in another tab - nothing. I can either get the container or the images but can't get both to work. I have done a bit of research and not sure what the answer is here. Found this as a fix:

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000px;
}

Modified it to this:

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000px;
}

and all of the content disappears - even the first carousel.  I tried creating unique CSS and function names but I can't get the second carousel to display properly or work.

Seems like there should be an easier way to pull up a second or third carousel in a tab?  Am I really going to need a unique .js for each carousel? Any suggestions?

---

OK - it's really only working if the carousel is in the first tab. none of the others work

Answer (score 1):

possibly here is your answer:

[jQuery multiple carousels in jQuery UI tabs do not work properly in Internet Explorer and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387172/jquery-multiple-carousels-in-jquery-ui-tabs-do-not-work-properly-in-internet-exp)

"This problem is because you are trying to create the carousel after you have created the tabbed interface. So probably jcarousel is trying to render the carousel inside a container whose display property is set to null (a non-active tab) . Since position and many other properties of this container can not be reliably determined, this will fail in most browsers. Please try rendering the carousel before, once the carousel is rendered, then create the tabs."

It worked for me ;)