# jQuery multiple carousels in jQuery UI tabs do not work properly in Internet Explorer and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jcarousel

I have a problem in the page whose URL can be seen below:

http://hero.mynet.com/new/

There is a tabbed structure at the middle bottom of page.Each tab consists one carousel working.And each carousel item (image) can be shown in an overlay when they are clicked.

I used jQuery 1.3.2 (I know it's old but I cannot change because of other depencies), jQuery UI 1.7.3, jCarousel 0.2.8 and FancyBox 1.3.4 to build this.

Problem can be seen in the screen shots of Internet Explorer and Chrome when 2nd or 3th tab clicked and prev button clicked.

What can caused this, I tried many things to fix this but none of the fixed my problem.

What do you recommend? It's difficult to change all structure to a new one because of the time planing of this job.

tHanks to all answers already now

**Internet Explorer Screen Shot**
[image: Internet Explorer Screen Shot]

**Chrome Screen Shot**

[image: Chrome Screen Shot]

Comment: sen koca siteyi yap mynete, sonra kodu oturtama , oluyor mu böyle :P (a Turkish joke since I guessed he's from Turkey) First create carousel, then the tabs as a callback function to successful loaded carousel. Also a jsfiddle would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because you are trying to create the carousel after you have created the tabbed interface. So probably jcarousel is trying to render the carousel inside a container whose display property is set to null (a non-active tab) . Since position and many other properties of this container can not be reliably determined, this will fail in most browsers. Please try rendering the carousel before, once the carousel is rendered, then create the tabs.

Comment: No, I render the carousels first after that I render tabs when document ready. Please check the source code. I also tried the reverse of this, both fails.